# How to deal with functions with compound types in Scala?

Tags: scala

I receive some input from a web service and I need to validate it and return the input and a message if the input could not be validated. So I have a possible idea on how to handle the problem and start to implement it but I soon realize that I'm unable to because of types. So I try and do it in a dynamic language, I look up the syntax for the language and under 10 minutes I have an implementation:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta


def generic_validator(dictionary):
    return {key: (value, message) for (key, (value, predicate, message)) in dictionary.items() if not predicate(value)}


inputDict = {
    'SomeInt': (11, lambda x: x < 10, 'Input should be less than ten'),
    'SomeString': ('Hello', lambda x: len(x) > 10, 'Input should be longer than ten characters'),
    'SomeDate': (date.today() - timedelta(days=1), lambda x: x >= date.today(), 'Date cannot be before today')
}

result = generic_validator(inputDict)

for k2, (v2, m2) in result.items():
    print(m2)
```

So it works and I can print the messages but I would like to do it in Scala (actually, it has to be in Scala since I have no say on the language used in the project). And so I realize the problem is that I don't know what the type of `inputDic` should be. I tried the following but was unsuccessful:

```
val inputDict = Map(
    "SomeInt" -> (11, (x: Int) => x < 10, "Input should be less than ten"),
    "SomeString" -> ("Hello", (x: String) =>  x.length > 10, "Input should be longer than ten characters"),
    "SomeDateTime" -> (DateTime.now().minusDays(1), (x: DateTime) => x.isAfter(DateTime.now()), "DateTime cannot be before now")
  )

def genericValidator(dict: Map[String, (Any, Any => Boolean, String)]): Map[String, (Any, String)] =
  dict.filter {
    case (_, (value, predicate, _)) => !predicate(value)
  }.map {
    case (key, (value, _, message)) => (key, (value, message))
  }

val result = genericValidator(inputDict)

Error:(14, 33) type mismatch;
               found : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(Any, org.joda.time.DateTime with String with Int => Boolean, String)]
               required: Map[String,(Any, Any => Boolean, String)]
               val result = genericValidator(inputDict)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the implementation as close to the original Python code, I would use something like:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

def genericValidator(dict: Map[String,(Any,Any=>Boolean,String)]) = {
  dict.collect { case (key, (value, predicate, message)) if !predicate(value) => (key, (value,message)) }
}

val inputDict: Map[String,(Any, Any=>Boolean, String)] = Map(
  "SomeInt" -> (11, { case x: Int => x < 10 }, "Input should be less than ten"),
  "SomeString" -> ("Hello", { case x: String =>  x.length > 10 }, "Input should be longer than ten characters"),
  "SomeDateTime" -> (DateTime.now().minusDays(1), { case x: DateTime => x.isAfter(DateTime.now()) }, "DateTime cannot be before now")
)

val result = genericValidator(inputDict)

for ((k2, (v2, m2)) <- result)
  println(m2)
```

Comment: I'm getting a compile error with both this and the original code: `error: too many arguments (3) for method ->: (y: B)(String, B)` ... also, the larger problem is this can't compile because functions are contravariant.

Comment: You need to import `DateTime` for this to work. I updated the answer to provide the import.

Comment: Doesn't look like an import problem, more like a syntax parse problem. Try running this in the REPL: `1 -> (1, { x => x + 1 }, 1)`. You'll get the same error.

Comment: Yeah, you have to annotate the type for the x argument: `1 -> (1, { x: Int => x + 1 }, 1)`

Comment: Any link to understand why an anonymous partial function is necessary?

Comment: In the case of the answer I posted, I'm using the `collect` method on [Map](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):scala.collection.Map[B]) which takes a `PartialFunction` as a parameter. In the case of the comment above, the compiler interprets an anonymous function literal `Int => Int` or `Function1[Int,Int]`

Comment: @osocron intuitively, your predicate has type `Any => Boolean`, which means _each_ of the predicates needs to be able to handle _any_ type at all, since the type system can't guarantee that you'll only pass an `Int` to a predicate corresponding to an `Int` value in the dictionary. So, a partial function succinctly handles _any_ input by matching on its type, at the cost of losing safety and throwing an exception if by mistake someone passes in the wrong type.

Comment: @Yawar, although in that case it is still not a `PartialFunction`. If we wanted it to be so, we would have to annotate it as `PartialFunction[Any,Boolean]` rather than `Any=>Boolean`. And then maybe in *genericValidator* make use of it by checking if the partial function is defined for its input before calling it: `dict.collect { case (key, (value, predicate, message)) if predicate.isDefinedAt(value) && !predicate(value) => (key, (value,message)) }`

Comment: Well, `PartialFunction[A, B]` is a subtype of `A => B` so at runtime the `{ case ... }` functions actually still are partial functions. With the match guard you suggest, we still have the possibility of an exception if the match fails.

Comment: The only difference is that [isDefinedAt](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html#isDefinedAt(x:A):Boolean) is only defined in the subtype `PartialFunction[A, B]`. Using that method we avoid `scala.MatchError`. Here's an [example](https://gist.github.com/sheaney/ded3dd522febf8112603239d27a674e0).